# problem in sign in with LinkedIn in angular and node (using passportjs)

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, linkedin-api, angular-social-login

I am having problem in logging in with LinkedIn, both in angular front-end and on node side using passport js. I guess It might be due to change in policy of LinkedIn after 1st march. i have following three files

Server file

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

 // set up routes
 app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
 app.use('/profile', profileRoutes);

  // create home route 
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('home');
   });

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app now listening for requests on port 3000'); 
  });
```

Routes file

```
 const router = require('express').Router();
 const passport = require('passport');

 // auth login
 router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
 res.render('login', { user: req.user });
 });

 // auth logout
 router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
 // handle with passport
 res.send('logging out');
 });

router.get('/google',
 passport.authenticate('linkedin'),
   function(req, res){
 // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this
 // function will not be called.
 });

  router.get('/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin'), (req, 
 res) => {
 res.send(req.user);
// res.redirect('/profile');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Paasport setup file

```
 const passport = require('passport');
 const LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
 passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
          clientID: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
         clientSecret: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
         callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback",
         scope: ['r_emailaddress','r_liteprofile'],
 }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
 // asynchronous verification, for effect...
 process.nextTick(function () {
 return done(null, profile);
   });
 }));
```

Comment: please provide some code as well as the error you are experiencing.

Comment: Please edit your original post with all the code.  this doens't seem to perform anything substantal related to your problem

Comment: code is added now, have a look

Comment: Pls have a look at this. https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/pull/63.   Apparently there were breaking changes but the origi al library wasnt updated.

Comment: At first glance, there seems to be some confusion in your router, server, and passport configuration strategy' code. As an example, you initialize passport `app.use(passport.initialize())` separately from your passport strategy registration. Why not keeping the passport's code all in the same module? You are calling the routes when the application has been initiated but don't you need the routes before starting the application server? Finally, to echo a previous user's comment, you need to log the type of error you get in the LinkedIn callback function and take it from there.